# CLI tool to use fanotify

Tags: linux, notification, command-line

[inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) - [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch)
[fanotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) - ?

I expect the tool to be able to reliably, recursively and scalably watch a directory and report events (added files, removed files, changed files) by outputting lines to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

There are some examples around "hello world" level on Github:

- [fsnoop](https://github.com/jeffwalter/fsnoop) prints a lot of events about everything. You can filter them;
- [fanotify_watch](https://github.com/proger/fanotify_watch) prints events for writing files;
- [fanotify-cmd](https://github.com/peadar/fanotify-cmd) - monitor just one file
- [fanotify](https://github.com/NegativeMjark/fanotify) - you can specify events, but I haven't managed to get any output from it

---

Update: one more notable tool: [fatrace](https://github.com/hgfluf/fatrace).